# Copying data validation from one worksheet to another in an excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I've got three worksheets setup.

The first contains reference data for my data validation list.

The second references the first sheet for a data validation drop down list. Something like `sheet1!$a1:$a3`

The problem arises when I try and copy the cell in sheet two that contains the data validation drop down list to a cell in *sheet 3* where the destination cell is empty.

I'm trying to copy excel data validation but when copied across to *sheet 3* it references the cells `$a1:$a3` but doesn't maintain the reference to *sheet 1* where the data for the drop down list is actually stored.

How can I copy the data validation such that when it is copied to *sheet 3* it still maintains the reference to sheet1 where the static data that makes up the list is.

Comment: Can you provide the code that is performing the copy?

Comment: I'm performing the copy manually. Ctrl + c then Ctrl + v on the other sheet

Comment: Try changing your reference to data validation to something like: `sheet1!$a$1:$a$3`

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? [This is only possible since Excel version 2010+](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/09/03/conditional-formatting-from-different-sheet/)

Comment: Hope I understood question correctly. Name your range for data validation as `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1","A3").Name="DataValid"`
and reference to this named range. It won't matter after this to which sheets you copy cells with validation.

Comment: Zac that's exactly what the reference looks at the moment in the data validation. The problem is that with the standard copy and paste manually which I have done from sheet two to sheet three the sheet1 part of the reference is dropped and the drop down list on sheet three just points to $a1:$a3. And by dropping that sheet reference on copy the drop data validation list automatically refers to just the cells on sheet three, kind of like a relative reference would. Where as I want it to be absolute and the list items for the data validation still remain as coming from sheet 1.

Comment: Ralph I am using excel 2010

Comment: Thanks. Ill try and see if naming the range where the static data for the drop down lists sit means that it will successfully copy to another worksheet and still maintain reference to sheet1. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, the pasted Data Validation list is not showing the corrrect information. In my workbook I needed multiple cells of DV to display info from the sheet labled "Parts" after they were copied to the sheet labled "Ascending".

What I had to do was select my newly, and thus far incorrectly, pasted material, go to the 'Data' tab and click into 'Data Validaion --> Data Validation' (drop down menu). From here I had to edit the source to reflect the origional sheet.

Was: =$C$4:$C$21

Edit: =Parts!$C$4:$C$21

This determines what sheet the data is being validated from. Once Ive done this, I can copy and paste a DV interal to whatever sheet I am working on.

For some reason **naming** the range from the origional sheet (Parts) did not carry over in the pasted DV. VLOOKUP and other formulas thankfully work fine.